# How to Add Multiple Dataframes Join How

Tags: dataframe, outer-join

I am running a notebook on some golf stats that I found. In the example, it has 2018 and 2019 stats in the model. If I want to add 2020 and 2021 to the data, how do I go about with the following code:

```
df_stats = df_2018.join(df_2019, how='outer', lsuffix='_2018', rsuffix='_2019')
```

No Coding experience FYI
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: I tried the concat one but I am getting errors now. I am not really sure what I am doing honestly..

Comment: I found a solution for it but I am sure there is an easy way around it. I joined 2018-2019 & 2020-2021 and rewrote the same code as the original one. It does the trick. Thanks

Comment: without seeing your dataframe and your expected output from that dataframe its hard to tell what are you trying to do and also it is necessary for testing purpose  **:/**...btw glad to know that you found solution without any help of others **:)**

Comment: I'll provide more information next time I run into an error. Thanks for taking the time to provide a solution. Appreciate it